# Localize a dynamically binding DropDownList in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, resx

I have a dropdownlist which binds with a database  table '**countries**'
The dropdownlist takes column **countryname** as its datatextfield and **countrycode** as datavaluefield.
Suppose this table has 3 entries which have respective column values as given below.

**India**   , **IN**
**Germany** , **DE**
**America** , **US**

and I am changing the culture to **de-DE**
I know to use resx file for a single static text.
Now, how can I localize the multiple datatextfield items to **de-DE** simultaneously??

Comment: As your data comes from a database table, i.e, it can change, why don't you keep the localized string also in database?

Comment: I hope these are master values. For master values you can use mapped resource file or store localization masterdata in DB.

Comment: I am looking for the method. I have to use this at many places. So Im not think that adding a localization column is a good Idea. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you need to join the collection of table rows with the values from the resource file on the value, then pack the data into a custom type to which you'll bind the `DropDownList`. So:

```
var tableRows = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>();
var resourceStrings = YourResourceClass.ResourceManager
        .GetResourceSet(culture: CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture,
            createIfNotExists: false,
            tryParents: true)
        .Cast<DictionaryEntry>();

var data = tableRows
        .Join(resourceStrings,
            row => row["countrycode"].ToString(),
            resource => resource.Key,
            (row, resource) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
                row["countrycode"].ToString(),
                resource.Value.ToString()))
        .ToArray();
```

Now, change binding properties of your `DropDownList` to:

```
ddl.DataTextField = "Value";
ddl.DataValueField = "Key";
```

And bind the datasource:

```
ddl.DataSource = data;
```

**EDIT**

To achieve the same result without using LINQ you'll need to load the resources into a dictionary and then iterate over the counties table to build the data source; something like this:

```
var resources = new Dictionary<string,string>();
var resourceSet = YourResourceClass.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(
    CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, false, true);
foreach(DictionaryEntry kvp in resourceSet)
{
    resources[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value.ToString();
}

var dataSource = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
foreach(DataRow in table.Rows)
{
    var countryCode = row["countrycode"].ToString();
    if(resources.ContainsKey(countryCode))
    {
        dataSource.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
            countryCode,
            resources[contryCode]));
    }
}
```

Next, bind the `dataSource` to your DropDownList and you're all set!

Comment: Can I achieve this without using Linq? (Because Im not currently using it in my project).. Thanks @RePierre ..